# PHP 500 internal error is not getting spot

Tags: php, json, http

I have gone over this code plenty of times can't spot a single error does any body see anything wrong with this script.
It gives me the following error:
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
<?php
session_start();

ob_start();

header("Content-type: application/json");

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');



$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'chat');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) { 

    echo '<p>Error:Could not connect to database.<br>
    Please try again later.</p>'; 
    exit; 
} 

try { 
    $currentTime = time(); 

    $session_id = session_id(); 

    $lastPoll = isset($_SESSION['last_poll']) ? 
        $_SESSION['last_poll'] : $currentTime; 

    $action = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && 
        ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') ? 
        'send' : 'poll'; 

    switch($action){ 
        case 'poll': 

            $query = "SELECT * FROM chatlog WHERE
            date_created >= ?"; 

         $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $lastPoll); 
            $stmt->execute(); 
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $message, $session_id, $date_created);
            $result = $stmt->get_result(); 

            $newChats = []; 

            while($chat = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 

                if($session_id == $chat['sent_by']){ 
                    $chat['sent_by'] = 'self'; 
                }else{ //good
                    $chat['sent_by'] = 'other'; 
                } 
                $newChats[] = $chat; 
            } 

            $_SESSION['last_poll'] = $currentTime; 

            print json_encode([ 
                'success' => true, 
                'messages' => $newChats
            ]); 
            exit; 

        case 'send': 

            $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';

            $message = strip_tags($message);

            $query = "INSERT INTO chatlog(message, sent_by, date_created)
            VALUES(?, ?, ?)"; 

            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $message, $session_id, $currentTime);
            $stmt->execute(); 

            print json_encode(['success' => true]); 
            exit; 
    } 
}catch(\Exception $e) { 
        print json_encode([ 
            'success' => false,
            'error' => $e->getMessage();
        ]);
    }
```

I have javascript file and an HTML file javascript file for processing the ajax request through, I am using jquery to handle all the ajax stuff. I don't know if that can deliver the error into the PHP file is that possible?

Comment: Get rid of your first php closing tag, and the 2nd php open tag, as there is a space character between them which will be output, then you are trying to set the header which needs to be done prior to any output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the semicolon

```
'error' => $e->getMessage();
```

to

```
'error' => $e->getMessage()
```

in one of your last lines.

And please use a editor with PHP syntax checking to avoid these problems.

Comment: man you certainly have relieved me of some stuff here.  thnx.

Comment: If this fixed the error then the **reason** would have been reported in your error log - you need to learn how to debug issues as well as prevent them.